# Поворот трехмерного вектора в заданной плоскости

Tags: c++, математика

Доброго времени суток.

**Задача:** Даны два трехмерных вектора - A и B. Данные вектора ортгональны друг другу и имеют длины равные единице.
Написать метод поворачивающий вектор A в плоскости задаваемой векторами A и B. Поворот в сторону от вектора A к вектору B считается положительным. Метод работает с градусами, а не с радианами. Ось y направлена вверх.

**Как я пытался решить задачу:** я создал класс Vector3D и включил в него следующий метод

```
void Vector3D::rotate(Vector3D* b, double angle) {
    // Находим координаты вектора, в локальной системе координат задаваемой векторами a и b.
    double localX = cos(degreeToRadian(angle));
    double localY = sin(degreeToRadian(angle));

    // умножаем векторы а и b на скаляры - длины компонентов результатирующего вектора
    double newXA = x * localX;
    double newYA = y * localX;
    double newZA = z * localX;
    double newXB = b->x * localY;
    double newYB = b->y * localY;
    double newZB = b->z * localY;

    // складываем полученные векторы
    x = newXA + newXB;
    y = newYA + newYB;
    z = newZA + newZB;
}
```

данный вектор вызывается у условного вектора А. Условный вектор В и угол поворота передается в качестве аргументов.

**Что не получается:** 
тестирую

```
void print(Vector3D* vector) {
    printf("vector(x=%f;y=%f;z=%f)\n", vector->getX(), vector->getY(), vector->getZ());
}

int main(void) {
    Vector3D a(-1,1,-1);
    a.setLength(1);
    Vector3D b(1,1,1);
    b.setLength(1);

    a.rotate(&b, 45);
    print(&a);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Ожидаю: vector(x=-0.000000;y=1.000000;z=-0.000000)

Получаю: vector(x=-0.000000;y=0.816497;z=-0.000000)

Длина вектора после поворота почему-то меняется. Скажите пожалуйста, где кроется ошибка.

Comment: Читай <<матрица поворота вокруг произвольной оси>>. Ось - векторное произведение. A * B https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае удобно использовать [SLERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) (сферическую интерполяцию), для ортогональных векторов она особенно проста

```
slerp(A, B, t) = Sin(Pi/2*(1-t))*A + Sin(Pi/2*t)*B  = 
                 Cos(Pi/2*t) * A  +  Sin(Pi/2*t) * B
```

с использованием диапазона t = 0..4, соответствующего углу от 0 до 2*Pi

---

P.S. Внимательное всматривание показало, что этот подход и используется, однако векторы a и b  в приведённом примере не ортогональны - это видно из того, что их скалярное произведение ненулевое

Comment: Действительно, а векторы то не ортогональны. @MBo, тогда последний к вам вопрос - выходит ошибка не в самом методе, а в неверных переданных данных? Метод написан верно?

Comment: Похоже, верно. Попробуйте в вашем пример обнулить z в обоих векторах. Метод можно модифицировать, чтобы он не только ортогональные векторы принимал, а любые неколлинеарные одинаковой длины, только придётся вычислять синус угла между ними

Answer (score 2):

В общем, как написали в комментариях выше - ошибка была в неверно введенных данных. Я расширил метод. Теперь он работает следующим образом: поворачивает вектора A на угол angle, в плоскости заданой векторами A и B. angle измеряется в градусах. Пложительным вращением считается вращение по направлению от вектора A к вектору B.

```
void Vector3D::rotate(Vector3D* b, double angle) {
/* 
* Находим вектор С лежащий в той же плоскости, что и вектора A и B. При этом
* вектор С будет ортогонален вектору A и ближайший угол поворота вектора А в сторону вектора С
* будет иметь тот же знак что и ближайший угол поворота вектора A в сторону вектора B.
* Для этого сперва найдем через векторное произведение - вектор temp, ортогональный векторам A и B,
* а затем найдем вектор C через векторное произведение векторов A и temp;
*/
double tempX = y*b->z - z*b->y;
double tempY = z*b->x - x*b->z;
double tempZ = x*b->y - y*b->x;
double cX = tempY*z - tempZ*y;
double cY = tempZ*x - tempX*z;
double cZ = tempX*y - tempY*x;

// Нормализуем вектора A и C
double lengthA = getLength();
double lengthC = sqrt(cX*cX + cY*cY + cZ*cZ);
double normAX = x / lengthA;
double normAY = y / lengthA;
double normAZ = z / lengthA;
double normCX = cX / lengthC;
double normCY = cY / lengthC;
double normCZ = cZ / lengthC;

// Находим координаты вектора, в локальной системе координат задаваемой векторами A и B.
double localX = cos(degreeToRadian(angle));
double localY = sin(degreeToRadian(angle));

// Умножаем векторы A и B на скаляры - длины компонентов результатирующего вектора
double newXA = normAX * localX;
double newYA = normAY * localX;
double newZA = normAZ * localX;
double newXB = normCX * localY;
double newYB = normCY * localY;
double newZB = normCZ * localY;

// Складываем полученные векторы
x = newXA + newXB;
y = newYA + newYB;
z = newZA + newZB;

// возвращаем нашему вектору прежнюю длину умножая его на скаляр.
x *= lengthA;
y *= lengthA;
z *= lengthZ;
}
```